# php echo the result while iterating through the loop

Tags: php, memory-management, buffer

I am execution loop and inside loop there is data processing function inside loop.

```
  for($i = 0 ; $i <=680 ; $i = $i + 40)
    {
          $url = 'http://www.yelp.com/biz/franchino-san-francisco?start=80';
          $root = yelp($url);
          var_dump($root);
    }
```

This loop takes long time to execute, and results are echoed at the end when entire loop completes.

How can I echo the result during each iteration?

Actually what happens here? does to result are stored in buffer and at the end echoed or what?

Comment: At the ending of loop, you wrote var_dump($root), so it will print the result. If he wants to write it every time, just go with the print_r or echo command at the end.

Comment: @user3540050 yes but he want it to print every loop. But it print out once.

Comment: And one other thing, you are calling third party API call in loop, so every time it will go for calling third party URL, so it takes some amount of time to proceed this loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP buffers the output.

If you want to output stuff to the browser immediately you can use the `flush()` and `ob_flush()` functions:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 680; $i += 40) {
    $url = 'http://www.yelp.com/biz/franchino-san-francisco?start=80';
    $root = yelp($url);
    var_dump($root);
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

Comment: 3 minutes left to selected answered. upvote if you think this que will help other

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing PHP through a web-page, this would be the behaviour.

PHP is a server side language and all code will be executed before displaying the output to the client. (using a browser)

If you want to display the result within the loop, better use console / cmd (command line)

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) is something that will help you use PHP with commandline.